# Application loss problem

Tags: applications, system-error, lg-g4, application-error

**Why are applications lost when rebooting?**

In every reboot this happens

Note: The LG G4 suffers from other problems such as the sudden stop of the Power button and also the high brightness ratio at reboot, which requires manually resetting the automatic light

---

**Divce name : LG G4 H818P**

**Processor : Snapdragon 808**

**Version year : 2015**

**Version system : 6.0 marshmallow**

---

[image]

Comment: Could it be those are installed on SD card?

Comment: @Izzy All applications installed on internal memory

Comment: Strange; then I have no clue, sorry. (With apps on SD card this can happen if the launcher starts a bit too early, i.e. before the card is mounted. That was a problem in the past, though I have long time not heard of it. Reason behind that is that the card is mounted only *after* the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast – which also triggers the launcher to be started – but that does not apply to internal storage)

Comment: @Izzy So what is the solution to this problem ...

Comment: @Izzy well I had problem with apps on SD card but not that only icons were set to default but I needed to install app from play store because they disappeared from there as well, is that a problem you are talking? What is workaround for this?

Comment: To the two of you: As I pointed out at the start of my previous comment, "I have no clue".